# ASP.NET Core, Devart, Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, asp.net-core-3.1, devart

Hy everbody,

I created a ASP.NET Core Web App which i run as a Windows Service.

That is working fine until i started to use Devart as DB-Provider for my Oracle-Database.
As soon as is include the Nuget-Package Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore in my Project i get the following Error when i try to start my Windows Service:

[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

I can start the Service again when i remove the Package Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore.

The Nuget-Package Devart.Data is also included but there is no Problem.
I can start the Service with the Package Devart.Data inculded without any Issue.

Unfortunately i need both Packages.

Maybe someone can give me a hint where i can find what the Problem with the Package Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore is?

Thank you very much.

I tried a view suggestions from there: [https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/#:~:text=Users%20experience%20the%20error%20message,respond%20in%20the%20time%20window](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/#:%7E:text=Users%20experience%20the%20error%20message,respond%20in%20the%20time%20window).

Comment: 1. Please check Windows Event Viewer if there are any errors related to your service with more information. 2. Does the issue arise after just installing the package Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore? Maybe, you create DbContext?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your Response. I have checked the Event Viewer but there was also only the Error Message above and nothing useful. I tried different scenarios. The Error occurs, when i include the Package without any using in the Source Code before i build. But i decided to User Devart.Oracle and OracleCommand Statement. I only write to one Table so it is absolutely enough. I am only still curios, why it does not work and where i can find the Reason :-). I will further investigate that behaviour after i finished the Windows Service for Production.